# Question about compound nouns without "de"

Tags: noms

I found many cases where two nouns are put together without a *de* connecting them, for example on my iPad I see options like `Stockage iPad` instead of `Stockage d’iPad`, `mode avion` rather than `mode d’/dans avion` (meanwhile `mode DE concentration`???), and somewhere else `rapport psychologie` but not `rapport sur/de psychologie`, and the most known one `adresse e-mail` (I think `adresse d’e-mail` fits just equally perfectly). It really confuses me that when and how to use such word form. *De l'aide ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times when the "de" adds to the weight of other "de's" in a sentence or there are space considerations (app terms), there is the possibility of leaving out the de between two nouns when followed by a de + a third noun. This is often seen in technical texts that tend to have a lot of de. meaning of or from.

By the way, mode avion is not one: it is just a translation of airplane mode.

Here is just one example.

It is found in technical texts and *sometimes* in descriptive business writing:

> SNCF Holding est un groupe d’entreprises spécialisé dans le transport
> et le logistique en Europe qui vise à développer les modes transport
> de toute entreprise ainsi que ceux liés au divertissement dans le
> secteur de tourisme avec ses offres de voyage par train.
> millereponses.com/emploi/…

[Emploi_SNCF](https://www.millereponses.com/emploi/sncf-a-france-recrutement-dans-le-transport-et-logistique/)

They used "mode transport" instead of the usual: *modes de transport* because of the "de toute entreprise", which would have made the sentence read like this: "les modes de transport de toute entreprise". This is not "colloquial". It is stylistic.

Answer (score 1):

Salut,

‘Stockage iPad’ est un simple raccourci: on pourrait dire ‘Stockage de l’iPad’- Il en est de même pour ‘rapport psychologie’ / ‘rapport de psychologie’

Pour ce qui est de ‘adresse e-mail’, ‘email’ complète ‘adresse’, donc pas besoin de ‘de’. C’est comme si vous disiez ‘adresse désactivée’ (≠ adresse de désactivée **??**)

NB: un e-mail = a message sent via an e-mail address
an email address = une adresse e-mail (et non une e-mail)

Comment: Merci, j'ai compris l'utilisation comme raccourcis, mais `‘email’ complète ‘adresse’` je ne comprends pas ça. Est-ce que « e-mail » est utilisé comme un adjectif ici ?

Comment: @SheechenHol Oui, on peut le considérer comme cela dans ce cas.